# pd.read_csv only parsing one out of two column dates

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I'm trying to read data from a csv and parsing dates but I found this issue in which only one of the columns gets a datetime format and the other one still remains an object.

```py
dtype = {'col1':'category','col2':'category','Start Date':'str','End Date':'str'}
dates = ['col3','col4']
df = pd.read_csv(filepath,dtype=dtype,parse_dates=dates,dayfirst=False)
```

Both date columns have same format.

when I do `df.info()` I get the following:
[df.info() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rZsL.png)

I tried using dayfirst input and the formatter but it didn't help.

I expect that both columns in the list would get datetime object but for some reason they aren't.

Update: tried to recreate a minimal reproducible data set by doing the code block below but this is behaving as expected, producing both Start Date and End Date columns as datetime.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['ABC','ABC','DCF','DCF'],
                   'Start Date':['12-31-2022','12-31-2022','12-31-2022','12-31-2022'],
                   'End Date':['12-31-2023','12-31-2023','12-31-2023','12-31-2023']
                  })

df.to_csv('test.csv',index=0)

df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
                  dtype={'col1':'category','Start Date':'str','End Date':'str'},
                  parse_dates = ['Start Date','End Date'],
                  dayfirst=False
                 )
df2.info()
```

Comment: Ciao Gian Flavio, do you mind providing a full [mcve]?

Comment: I tried making a minimal reproducible example but it turns out that when I try to create synthetic data to mimic the error I get the expected result. Please have a look at the main post to see what I tried to do for creating the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Are you sure that you shouldn't use `dates=['Start Date', 'End Date']`?

Comment: I get an error that read_csv get unexpected argument dates. Lastime I check it was supposed to be parse_dates since I'm passing the dtype as str.